# How to interleave a semaphore on a function?

Tags: c, fork, semaphore

I am struggling with a part of my multi-process code,
where I share a variable and increment it for a function call.

```
Struct ShMem{
  int counter;
  sem_t mutex;
};

void foo(int counter){
    sem_post(&mem->mutex);
    // complex calculation
}

ShMem *mem;
void main(){
    for(...){
        switch(fork()){
            case 0:
                sem_wait(&mem->mutex);
                mem->counter++;
                // no interruption between these steps wanted
                foo(mem->counter);
                exit(0);
        }
    }       
}
```

I split the wait and post function of the mutex on main and foo.

My intension is to not get interrupted between the increment of the
counter and the function call and let the complex part of foo run in paralell.

This aproach isn't working, since it hangs anywhere.
Maybe I use the wrong mechanism here, any suggestions ?

Comment: `fork` creates an entirely new process, with its own memory space. The two don't see the same `mem` by default.

Comment: I assume you want the mutex to inhibit changes of `mem->counter` before it is copied for the call to `foo`? Then why not copy it yourself into a separate variable, release the mutex and *then* call `foo` with your copied value?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude correctly, this is what I try to achive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did as you said and it is working. Thank you.
Can you answer it so I can close the question ?

Comment: Something like that yes, but you might want `row = ++mem->row` instead. Will make the `foo` function more stand-alone. However, it might not solve your problem if you have deadlocks or other problems. It's really hard to say anything with only the little code you show or the vague failure description.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it actualy solved the problem.